# If A is a prerequisite for B, what is a noun describing B in relation to A?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to find a noun that describes the thing enabled by the prerequisite. It should be able to work in the sentence "B is a(n) ___ for/of A", in which A and B are both skills.

For instance (this may be debatable, but for the sake of example), perhaps walking(A) is a prerequisite for running(B). Then running is a(n) ____ for/of walking.

I almost went with "result", but that didn't work well in this situation because being able to do A doesn't necessarily imply being able to do B.

Answer (score 4):

If a is always (and absolutely) a prereq of b, then b is dependent on a.

Comment: Aha. In noun form as requested, "dependency" works well.

Answer (score 0):

Running is a *progression* from walking.

Running is an *improvement* on walking.